# npx requires re-installation of packages every time

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Currently using npx as a workaround for packages installed globally by npm as commands can never be found despite all attempts at exporting to the correct path.

npx works in finding the command but has to reinstall the package every time to find it which means multiple uses of the same package runs into problems.

I've tried using the npx --no-install but then npx runs into the same problem as I did with "command not found" being the result.

All this is attempted through the ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my issue. The npx workaround was never going to work when my npm pathing was acting up. Had to reinstall npm (again) and manually create a global directory rather than use the default. Then had to export that path variable and append it to .bashrc confirm it with "source /.bashrc" and then restart the terminal. On restart everything worked fine and had no further problems with npm installs.